# How do I add a MySQL super user with root-like permissions?

Tags: mysql, connection, users

Using PhpMyAdmin on XAMPP, I want to add a super user that has the same privileges as 'root'@'localhost'.

This is because I want to create a MySQL instance that my local machine will serve as a remote database server.

Comment: Are you talking about a system user or a MySQL user? That's two unrelated things.

Comment: Yes a user to connec to MySQL. thru phpmyadmin panel

Comment: A more pertinent question would be why you need a root-level user with non-localhost access? What specific things do you need this user to do? Super-user access is locked to localhost for a very good reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the grants of root by executing "show grants for 'root'@'localhost';". This command will give you some output similar to this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then you can simply replace the username/password/host out of the shown grant query, for example like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'anotheruser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'anotherpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This should create a user 'anotheruser'@'%' with the specified password, and give it the same rights as 'root'@'localhost' has.

Comment: It's worth noting that identified by password 'xxx' expects a hashed password in input, otherwise it will return an error "Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number".  If you want to use a cleartext password, then you should run identified by 'clearpassword'